# A difficult equation containing exponent 2 and 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I couldn't solve this equation:

$$ \frac{2}{x^2} + \frac{2}{2x} - \frac{(x+1)^2}{x^3} = \frac{1}{27} $$

Do I have to multiply everything by $x^3$ and also the righthand side $1/27$? $1 \cdot x^3/27 \cdot x^3$?

Am I doing this right: $2x^3/x^5)+(2x^3/2x^4)-...$

Thanks.

Comment: You are multiplying all terms by $\frac{x^3}{x^3}$, but this isn't necessary. The equation still holds if you simply multiply both sides by $x^3$ (so that $\frac{2}{x^2}$ becomes $2x$ etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easyest way is as follows:

$\frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{2x}-\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^3}=\frac{1}{27}$

$\frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{2x}-\frac{x^2}{x^3}-\frac{2x}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^3}=\frac{1}{27}$

$\frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^3}=\frac{1}{27}$

$-\frac{1}{x^3}=\frac{1}{27}$

$x^3=-27$     $x=-3$.

Comment: damn I miscalculated.

Comment: kmitov, thanks for a simple and plain answer.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\frac{2}{x^{2}}+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x^{2}+2x+1}{x^{3}}=\frac{1}{27}$$

Multiplying through by $27x^3$ gives $$\begin{align}
54x+27x^{2}-27x^{2}-54x-27&=x^{3}\\-27&=x^{3}\\x&=-3
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{2x} -\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^3}=\frac{1}{27}$$

$$\implies \frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{2x} -\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^3}=\frac{1}{27}$$

$$\implies\frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{2x} -\frac1{x}-\frac{2}{x^2} -\frac{1}{x^3}=\frac{1}{27}$$
$$\implies -\frac{1}{x^3}=\frac{1}{27}$$

$$x^3+27=0 \implies (x+3)(x^2-3x+9)=0$$

One root is $x=-3$.
*OR*
$$x^2-3x+9=0$$

$$x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-36}}{2} = \frac{3\pm3\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$